# Inserting to next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert data in the next available row however it keeps missing out lots of rows which are blank.

My code is below:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Recipe creater")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Recipes")

    Call Pasterecipedetails

    copySheet.Range("b6:g6", Range("b6:g6").End(xlDown)).Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Sub Pasterecipedetails()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Recipe creater")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Recipes")

    copySheet.Range("c2:e2").Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
copySheet.UsedRange.Copy
nextRow = pasteSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row + 1
pasteSheet.Cells(nextRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: This skips empty cells if they have been used before. Entering in data into A1, A2, A3 and deleting it, then running the code will skip to A4.

Comment: that true when use.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row but if we used usedrange.specialcells ..... we get last down row of used range i tried that